# bash python no such file or directory: why is my file path different from what I specified?

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a shell script on Windows 10. I've also turned "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature on, because the script needs to run a package that asks me to do so during installation.

My path for my programs as:
`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Myname/Desktop/Myfolder`

Then I tried to run the shell script I have stored in a specific folder (and directly called the working directory) by:

`python /Users/Myname/Desktop/Myfolder/Mysubfolder/create_fa.py`

But this gives me this error:

`C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Program Files/Git/Users/Myname/Desktop/Myfolder/Mysubfolder/create_fa.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I'm confused because I specified where my `create_fa.py` file was stored, but when I run the shell script, it seems like it's trying to look my `create_fa.py` file at a different directory from which I specified. Why is the script looking for a different directory?

Comment: Instead of `PATH`, you should be setting `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: What does "run python on Git" mean? What does this have to do with git? Also, why are you passing a linux-style path with forward slashes to python when you're on Windows?

Comment: @Aran-Fey  I turned the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature on because I needed to use some other package that basically told me to use Linux-style commands. Is that a potential problem?

Comment: I suspect that `/` is probably resolving to `"C:/Program Files/Git"` somehow. Are you using Git Bash as your command line?

Comment: The problem is that your question makes no sense. Git is a version control system, you can't "run" anything in it. And you really should've included that information about the linux subsystem from the start.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Git comes with a bash terminal and can be used to run scripts much like powershell.

Comment: This is my first time running this type of script (got it from someone else) and looks like my lack of knowledge in terminology caused a lot of confusion. I edited the question, but basically I'm running a shell script (.sh), and when I run the script, it runs with "Git for Windows".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `python` doesn't look at `$PATH` at all.  If you have `script.py` in multiple PATH folders, how do you expect `python` to differentiate which `script.py` to run?

What `python` does is look into the current directory, i.e. `C:/Program Files/Git/`  You'll need to step back out that folder for a relative path, or supply the absolute path.

e.g. if your bash session is currently at `/Users/Myname/` then all you need to do is:

`python Desktop/Myfolder/Mysubfolder/create_fa.py`

Or pass in your user folder as absolute path:

`python ~/Desktop/Myfolder/Mysubfolder/create_fa.py`

Comment: I thought I was supplying the absolute path (in the second line of the code I have in my question) - how is that different from what you're suggesting? Sorry if I'm missing something completely obvious here.

Comment: On an actual Linux OS, you'd be right.  But Git recognizes the root `/` from its own directory (`C:/Programs/Git` in your case).  If you run `ls /` you see the contents inside `/Git` folder.  The actual root on WIndows would be `/C`.

Comment: Ah okay, so basically I needed to say `python /C/Users/...`. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm running a shell script (.sh), and when I run the script, it runs with "Git for Windows"

This is where the path "corruption" is coming from.

The Git Bash terminal creates a "linux-esque" directory hierarchy (sort of), with `/` (the "root" directory) set to `C:/Program Files/Git`. So, when you use the path `/Users/Myname/Desktop/Myfolder/Mysubfolder/create_fa.py`, Git Bash resolves that to `C:/Program Files/Git/Users/Myname/Desktop/Myfolder/Mysubfolder/create_fa.py`, as you've seen.

From Git Bash, you can access your normal directories like this:

- `~` = %USERPROFILE% (your user directory)
- `/c/...` = Directories under `C:\`, so your desktop would be `/c/Users/username/Desktop`

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful!